# Closest Combined Match in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to come up with a formula that gives me the closest match based on multiple criteria.
This only applies for those names with Valid = "N" (Column I), or else their own name is returned.
For example, Bob has the closest numbers combined to Susan for each day.

I rearranged all of the "valid" names in the table to the right so that Bob does not return "Bob" as the closest match (since we only want to return names that are valid anyways).

I have attached an image of the data below (with column J being my desired results)
[image: Excel Table]

| Name | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Valid (Y/N) | Desired Combined Closest Match | Calculated Closest Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 100 | 25 | 750 | 40 | 750 | 750 | 750 | N | Susan | Susan |
| Susan | 100 | 25 | 500 | 25 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | Y | Susan | Susan |
| Karen | 75 | 30 | 500 | 50 |  |  |  | Y | Karen | Karen |
| Michele | 100 | 30 | 500 | 50 |  |  |  | Y | Michele | Michele |
| Tom | 75 | 30 | 240 | 30 |  |  |  | Y | Tom | Tom |
| Rob | 100 | 30 | 1000 | 30 |  |  |  | Y | Rob | Rob |
| Brian | 100 | 30 | 1000 | 50 |  |  |  | N | Rob | Susan |
| Stacy | 100 | 30 | 500 | 50 |  |  |  | Y | Stacy | Stacy |
| Rachel | 100 | 30 | 500 | 50 | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | Y | Rachel | Rachel |
| Jeff | 100 | 30 | 500 | 50 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | N | Susan | Susan |

I am able to do this only using 1 column of data, but I am unsure how to combine them. I used INDEX, MATCH, MIN, and ABS functions to figure out the closest match based on one column (Sunday). Here is an example of my formula for Brian (it is supposed to return "Rob" as the result, but returns "Susan" because I only am using one day of data):
=IF(I8="Y",A8,INDEX($M$2:$M$8,MATCH(MIN(ABS($N$2:$N$8-B8)),ABS($N$2:$N$8-B8),0)))

Comment: It is much easier to help , if you provide your sample data as text within the question and not as screenshot. At the best you use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)

Comment: How about factoring in all columns by calculating the correlation matrix between all Names? Then you could always pick the 'closest match' as the name with the highest correlation.